# How can i use a variable in a for loop in a command ? (c#)

Tags: c#, for-loop, variables

So i have a matrix of buttons, from a1f to a10f and from a to j, so a1f is on the top left and j10 is on the buttom right.

I want to to something like this:

```cs
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
      a{i}f.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_1_Rebellion;
      b{i}f.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_2_Rebellion;
      a{i}f.Enabled = false;
      a{i}f.Tag = "playerShip";
      b{i}f.Enabled = false;
      b{i}f.Tag = "playerShip";
  }
```

so the first loop would be:

```cs
a1f.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_1_Rebellion;
b1f.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_2_Rebellion;
a1f.Enabled = false;
a1f.Tag = "playerShip";
b1f.Enabled = false;
b1f.Tag = "playerShip";
```

the second would be:

```cs
a2f.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_1_Rebellion;
b2f.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_2_Rebellion;
a2f.Enabled = false;
a2f.Tag = "playerShip";
b2f.Enabled = false;
b2f.Tag = "playerShip";
```

and so on..

a{i}f or a[i]f isnt working.

Comment: You can't make a variable reference that way. Probably better to store your button references in arrays so you can index into it to get the references.

Comment: create a array of `Button`s and access it by `for (i = 1; i < 11; i++)  {      af[i].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't iterate the controls, you could store them in a temp array.

But you would probably better doing by generating the controls. It might be the next level for improvement. For now, you could try this:

For example:

```
// create arrays which contains the controls.
var aShips = new [] { a1f, a2f, a3f, a4f, a5f, a6f, a7f, a8f, a9f, a10f };
var bShips = new [] { b1f, b2f, b3f, b4f, b5f, b6f, b7f, b8f, b9f, b10f };

// notice the 0  and the < 10, because arrays are zero-indexed
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // now you can access them via the array. 
    aShips[i].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_1_Rebellion;
    aShips[i].Enabled = false;
    aShips[i].Tag = "playerShip";

    bShips[i].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1mal2_2_Rebellion;
    bShips[i].Enabled = false;
    bShips[i].Tag = "playerShip";
}
```